# How to convert bytes into doc file and download it using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to use Byte data to create .doc file.
I have bytes data here in last line. I have to convert byte data into .doc file and need to download it.

```
irsc = new CustomReportCredentials(ReportServerUserName, ReportServerPassword, ReportServerDomain);
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = rptUrl;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/" + ReportFolder + "/" + _reportName; 
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters); 
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh(); 
bytes = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
```

Comment: please format your question properly

Comment: If your intention is to make a response with the file from server side then having the document as byte[] is perfectly fine. You can just response byte[] directly to the client. Just need to specify mimeType, file name, etc.

Comment: doc file? Your code says pdf, not doc. What kind of report are you trying to convert?

Comment: FYI: ["You can access the list of available rendering extensions using the `ListRenderingExtensions` method in `ServerReport`"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252199.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("Foo.txt", arrBytes); // Requires System.IO
```

If you have an enumerable and not an array, you can use:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("Foo.txt", arrBytes.ToArray()); // Requires System.Linq
```

Comment: Given the fact this is asp.net, I think that with "download it" they mean "send it to the client as download", not "save it to local disk".